# Calculating the mean of different insect orders per camera per hour and plotting

Tags: r, mean, standard-error

Hi I have dataset consisting of different camera’s with observations per date and hour and it looks approximately like this:

```
d <- read.table(text=
'Camera     datehour    order        observations
 1          2019051212  Araneae      2
 1          2019051213  Araneae      4
 1          2019051214  Lepidoptera  3
 1          2019051215  Lepidoptera  2
 2          2019051213  Lepidoptera  5
 4          2019051214  Araneae      3  
 4          2019060423  Araneae      2
 5          2019070503  Araneae      1
 5          2019070503  Araneae      6 ', header=TRUE)
```

As you can see camera 1 has filmed for four hours, camera 2 for one hour,  camera 4 for two hours and camera 5 one hour. I would like to add an extra column containing the mean per camera per hour per order which should look like this:

```
Camera datehour     order        observations   mean
1      2019051212   Araneae         2           0.5
1      2019051213   Araneae         4           1
1      2019051214   Lepidoptera     3           0.75
1      2019051215   Lepidoptera     2           0.5
2      2019051213   Lepidoptera     5           5
4      2019051214   Araneae         3           1.5 
4      2019051223   Araneae         2           1
5      2019070503   Araneae         1           1
5      2019070503   Lepidoptera     6           6
```

Edit: "The mean is calculated by dividing the unique 'datehour' count per camera with the observation.

Example: camera 1 has 4 unique 'datehour' so the mean of the first observation of Araneae(2) is 0.5"

Eventually, I would like to plot the data having the order on the x-axis and the mean on the y-axis (ignoring the camera number). Would this be the correct way and could I calculate a standard error with this?

I tried google but everything seems a bit overwhelming to be honest and I couldn’t find the answer I was looking for.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: looks like only camera 5 takes into account the `order`?

Comment: How are you calculating `mean` column? Can you show with an example?

Comment: Hi @DanielO, Camera 5 recorded for 1 hour but with 2 different orders. So the mean is still 1 and 6. thanks

Comment: Hi @Henrik, By both date and time. Thank you

Comment: @Henrik, I understand the issue now. If you look at `Camera 5` the same hour can be on multiple rows if observations of both `order`'s were made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a tricky one. Not the most elegant solution, but it works. In Base-R

```
d$mean <- unlist(lapply(split(d,d$Camera), function(x) x$observations/sum( sub(" .*","",unique(paste(d$Camera,d$datehour))) %in% x$Camera[1])))


> d
  Camera   datehour       order observations mean
1      1 2019051212     Araneae            2 0.50
2      1 2019051213     Araneae            4 1.00
3      1 2019051214 Lepidoptera            3 0.75
4      1 2019051215 Lepidoptera            2 0.50
5      2 2019051213 Lepidoptera            5 5.00
6      4 2019051214     Araneae            3 1.50
7      4 2019060423     Araneae            2 1.00
8      5 2019070503     Araneae            1 1.00
9      5 2019070503     Araneae            6 6.00
```